# No such revision subversion

Tags: svn

We use version svn 1.6.12. After recovering lvm on the machine, it gives an error when connecting : svn: E160006: No such revision 12526. In the revs directory there really is no such revision 12526 as others since 7739 and many other. I can not do a dump and synchronization, because it is interrupted constantly on non-existent revisions. What is interesting is that in the revprops folder there are these numbers, which are absent in revs. Tell me, please, how can I restore the repository? 
Thank.

Comment: I think the repository was on crashed LVM, yes? It seems it's in corrupted state - do you have backup from repository?

Comment: Unfortunately no backup copy

Comment: I tried to restore svnadmin recover and got answer.- "Recovery completed" . But when I do the svnadmin verife check, the error reappears No such revision. When I connect through tortoisesvn, the status is revision file lacks trailing newline.